# Does an Australia ETA (subclass 601) or eVisitor (subclass 651) visa ever have a no further stay condition?

Tags: visa, working-visas, australia

We are planning to return to Australia and I was wondering if the *ETA (subclass 601)* or *eVisitor (subclass 651)* can have the "no further stay" condition attached (as could be the case with Work & Holiday visas). I am aware that you can only stay for 3 months in a 12 month period, but is it technically possible to apply for another visa (e.g. Temporary Work (Skilled) visa (subclass 457) through employer nomination), while being in the country on this simple eVisitor class?

I know that you can apply for Temporary Work (Skilled) visa (subclass 457) onshore and that you can apply for a bridging visa while your application is being reviewed. However, this is only possible if your visa does NOT have a "no further stay" condition, hence my question.

The official information available [online](http://www.border.gov.au/about/corporate/information/fact-sheets/52b-nfc) does state this condition is mandatory for Visitor visas (subclass 600), **but says nothing about the eVisitor visa (subclass 651)**.

*There is also a way to check imposed visa conditions online here:*
http://www.border.gov.au/Trav/check-your-visa-and-work-entitlements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just applied for an eVisitor (subclass 651) which took all of 20min to come through and is free of charge. I then looked up the imposed visa conditions and there was **NO** condition regarding `No further stay` applied.

*So the answer is, there generally is no condition applied preventing you from applying for another visa onshore (in Australia), which is great!*

However, I also would advice that the Visitor visa (subclass 600) will generally have this condition (8503) regarding `no further stay` attached to the visa. As mentioned before, you can always check all conditions applying to your personal visa right here: http://www.border.gov.au/Trav/check-your-visa-and-work-entitlements